# How to use SQL UNION operation

Tags: sql, union, union-all

```
  SELECT a.*

  FROM tableA AS a

  LEFT JOIN tableC AS c
  ON c.id = a.catid

  LEFT JOIN tableD AS d
  ON d.id = a.created_by

  INNER JOIN tableE AS e
  ON e.content_id = a.id

  WHERE a.access IN (1,1,5)
  AND c.access IN (1,1,5)
```

I am trying to use UNION ALL/ UNION operation instead of IN operation in SQL. I am having troubles to figure out how to convert the above query to use UNION. How Can I convert the above query to use UNION

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?  Does the query work?  Provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: I don't see where you would use `UNION` instead of `IN`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know how to convert this query to use UNION operation instead of IN operation

Comment: There is no need to convert this query to use `UNION` instead of `IN`, if the query is running fine with `IN`.

Comment: I was thinking that UNION operation is faster than the IN operation. Which is the faster one?

Comment: Note: the `AND c.access IN (1,1,5)` will effectively tun the `LEFT JOIN tableC AS c` INTO a plain JOIN (because `c.access` cannot be NULL NOTE2: `AND c.access IN (1,1,5)` IS equivalent to `AND c.access IN (1,5)` (similar for a.acccess )

Comment: Is this a real query? If that is the case I think it is possible to simplify it a bit

Comment: There are some cases where `union all` (and sometimes even `union`) is can perform better than a complex query.  This query is unlikely to be one of those cases.

Comment: IMO, this problem looks highly artificial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
(
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c
ON c.id = a.catid
WHERE a.access = 1
AND c.access = 1
)

UNION ALL

(
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableC AS c
ON c.id = a.catid
WHERE a.access = 5
AND c.access = 5
)

UNION ALL

(
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT JOIN tableD AS d
ON d.id = a.created_by
INNER JOIN tableE AS e
ON e.content_id = a.id
)
```